# MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Throwing from logger shutdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After updating the Visual Studio to 15.8.0, I could not open any projects with the following error.

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Throwing from logger shutdown
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type  'Microsoft.Build.Framework.IEventSource3' from assembly >'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.ShutdownComponent()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.ShutDownLoggingService()

I tried to repair visual studio.  I even tried to reinstall.  Please help in trying to debug this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following solved for me.

> gacutil /u Microsoft.Build.Framework
>
> gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll"

Comment: Worked like magic  (with Visual studio developer command line - admin).  Thanks for quick response.